# Link to private google calendar

Tags: html, oauth, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm displaying events from a private Google Calendar on my CRM. I get them by authenticating using the google API. The problem is in my browser i use 2 google accounts - the first one is my personal one and the second is the one that has access to the Google Calendar I'm fetching. When I click on the link for the event it takes me to Google Calendar and says there is no such event, because by default I'm using my personal account, so i need to switch to the one that has access to the Google Calendar I'm fetching. Is there a way to tell Google that this is an event for the other user and when i click the link it takes me to the event witht the user already switched?

At the moment the link to the event looks something like this:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NWoyODJ2NDVtMz.........
```

Comment: This depends a lot on your code but you are going to need to either load a new set of authentication from a stored refresh token or refresh the authentication by prompting for re-consent https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#re-consent

Comment: @DaImTo i am already authenticated with OAuth 2.0 when i display the calendar links, but what do I add to them so that when I get redirected to Google Calendar the account is already switched?

Comment: you are authetcated with Oauth2 on two seprate accounts. You need to swap from the two seprate accounts using the access token or the refresh token